# Splitting and swapping names

Tags: r, string, split

I have names in the following format;

```
name1
"brown-john"
name2
"bloggs-joe"
```

To which i want to now change to read john brown and joe bloggs. Removing the '-' they are separated by isnt too much if an issue but im struggling to flip the names if anyone knows how thats possible?

Comment: Beware of [making any assumptions about names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/). But why not just split the names?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `gsub`:

```r
name <- c(name1 = "brown-john", name2 = "bloggs-joe")
gsub("(.*)-(.*)", "\\2 \\1", name)
#       name1        name2 
#"john brown" "joe bloggs"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another

```
> sapply(strsplit(name,"-"),function(y){paste(rev(y),collapse=" ")})
       name1        name2 
"john brown" "joe bloggs"
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use string.split and use the splitted strings as required

string name = "brown-john";

var splitName = name.Split('-');

name = splitName[1] + " " + splitName[0];

Comment: OP's looking for a `R` solution